# vue3-date-time-picker does not trigger @click event

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-jetstream

jetstream application I have installed vue3-date-time-picker with the below code

```
<Datepicker :disabledDates="disabledDates"  @click="doSomething" v-model="date" inline autoApply :minDate="new Date()" :maxDate="maxdate" :enableTimePicker="false"></Datepicker>

   setup() {
            const date = ref();
            var today = new Date();
            const mxdate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+2, today.getDate())
                
            return {
                    date,
                    maxdate
                }
        },
methods: {

        doSomething(){
            alert(this.date)
            alert("hello")
            console.log("Check date")
        },
      }
```

When I click on a particular date, I want it to call the doSomething() method but nothing happens and the trigger doesn't work. No error is also shown. How to go about it? am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There's no `@click` event available for this library. For list off all available events, check out their docs [here](https://vue3datepicker.com/api/events/)

However you can do this, as there's already a two-way binding with `date`

```
<Datepicker model="date" ...></Datepicker>
```

you can watch for changes in `date`, that's probably equal to a `@click` event (if you need to do take some action whenever the date changes)

```
// add import
import { watch } from "vue";

// then inside setup
watch(data, (newDate, prevDate) => {
  /* ... */
})
```